# Repeating loop until enter is pressed

Tags: c++, loops, animation, while-loop

*For anybody else finding this question, this can be accomplished with the kbhit() function in the conio.h library.  Just insert !kbhit() where I put SOMETHING and it will loop correctly, I am looking for a way to do this without a library, however.*

I'm a beginner trying to create a simple animation in the console.  The animation would have the word UP going up the right hand of the console and the word DOWN going down the right hand side. So far I have gotten the animation to complete one iteration of this, but I'm trying to make it so that it repeats and it looks like the texts wraps back to the top or bottom and does it again until the user presses the ENTER key.

My book (I'm self teaching from a textbook) makes it seem that its possible without any specific libraries except for iostream and windows.h but help that includes library functions is welcome too, it is a learning experience after all. Thanks a ton!

A little explanation of the code would be that I set the coordinates of the UP and DOWN starting positions and then move the cursor, delete the previous line it was on with a space and then increment two and put a new word.  I would guess that I could use a second while loop to somehow check if the ENTER key has been pressed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD upPos = {20,28};
    COORD downPos = {50, 0};
    char endState;
    while ( SOMETHING )
    {
      COORD upPos = {20,28};
      COORD downPos = {50, 0};
        while (upPos.Y >=0)
        {
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen,upPos);
            cout << "UP" << endl;
            upPos.Y++;

            SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen,upPos);
            cout << "  " << endl;
            upPos.Y -=2;

            SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen,downPos);
            cout << "DOWN" << endl;
            downPos.Y--;

            SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen,downPos);
            cout << "    " << endl;
            downPos.Y+=2;

            Sleep(100);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Check the `std::istream::read` function.

Comment: @Ostricho Welcome to SO! If you have an answer, you should post it as an answer instead of adding it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a custom "GetAsyncKeyState" function that will use #IFDEF for windows and linux to choose the appropriate GetAsyncKeyState() or equivalent. For ex

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))
    {
       exit = true;
    }
```